# How can I draw a tree to represent combinations?

Tags: combinations, trees

I understand how to systematically draw a tree for permutations. How do you do this for combinations? In my book, I don't see a system to avoid repetitions. I'd like to draw a tree of 5C3 if possible. Any thoughts?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured out the pattern, at least roughly:

[image]